# WATER and CLOTH simulation

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I am relatively new to BLENDER and I was wondering if there is an elegant chance of combining the water simulation with the cloth simulation.

I would like to simulate a washing machine like device, where clothes are interacting with water (and structure). I have done the water simulations and cloth simulations separately in blender before, but combining the two seems to be quite a challenge.

All the support is most appreciated.

Thanks, Uroš

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is coupling, where two physics simulations interact with each other. Unfortunately, Blender does not support this and can only, like you have said, run the individual simulations. You could try this, but note that the results won't be accurate:

1. Run the cloth simulation, maybe with some settings that make it look like it is floating in water (lower gravity, more air resistance)
2. After baking the cloth simulation (this is important), give the cloth object fluid physics and set to effector.
3. Run the fluid simulation.

Though this may produce some realistic results, it will look fake after closer analysis. This is because the fluid reacts to the movement of the cloth, but the cloth does not react to the fluid. There are some simulation programs that do support these physics interactions, most notably Houdini FX. Unfortunately, nearly all of those softwares will cost money.

Comment: Thanks Eric, yes that is what I thought. Combining two physics of this nature in one analysis in Blender does not seem to be an option. I can get around the problem by changing the cloth to a rigid solid part I believe right? Do you also maybe know if the buoyancy effect is acting on the rigid components while in the fluid in Blender. Also, do you maybe know of any alternative to Blender that would have the cloth and fluid iteration solved? Many thanks, Uroš